# How to resolve dependencies of a custom RubyGem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a ruby gem which has a dependency on another gem.

Eg. I'm writing a gem called "ABC" which has a dependency on "XYZ". How to make my gem install "XYZ" automatically when I try to install "ABC" ?

Comment: You might find useful the Rubygems documentation on [declaring dependencies](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing a gem called "ABC" which has a dependency on "XYZ". How to make my gem install "XYZ" automatically when I try to install "ABC" ?

You shouldn't try to make your gem install the dependencies automatically. That's *literally* what RubyGems is for. RubyGems resolves dependencies automatically, there is no need for your gem to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just define required dependency in your `.gemspec` file:

https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'example', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
```

and they will be installed when your gem is being installed (or just used if the dependency is already there).

There's also a way to install the dev dependencies: https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_development_dependency

```
spec.add_development_dependency 'example', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
```

for those gems that are required for developing (like `rspec`) but not needed for the final product to work.